# Address field order on Contact's "edit" page

Tags: addresses

How can I change the order of the address' fields on the page where I can edit the conatct's details?

Now I see the fields city, than postal code, than country, but I'd like to have postal code first, than city, and than country.

In the Address.tpl file is only so much:

```
{foreach item=addressElement from=$addressSequence}
     {include file=CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Address/$addressElement.tpl}
```

How can I edit `$addressSequence`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have a significantly easier time just reordering the fields with a little jQuery in a custom version of the template you referenced above.

For completeness... You can see the sequence function here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5dde2c09c10513a22464e8c4abcb6b4ca17fc1cb/CRM/Utils/Address.php#L288

Answer (score 0):

[This doesn't answer your question, but may be useful anyway]

You can change the order of address fields used for *displaying* the address at `Administer > Localization > Address Settings` and change the `Address Display` section.

If you want to change which address fields are available for *editing* then see the `Address Editing` section of the same page.  But that does not let you determine the order of fields when editing.